TextArea - Javascript Validation using CSS Pseudo Class and Regex
a.) Currently i have a php / html form with input validation using html input patterns.
b.) To show that the input entered is correct, I use the css pseudo property user-invalid / user-valid via a class 'check_valid' as below;
input.check_valid:user-invalid     { border: 4px dotted red;   }
input.check_valid:user-valid       { border: 4px solid  green; }

c.) The issue is with textareas and the lack of pattern support. What i do have is;
textarea.check_valid:user-invalid  { border: 4px dotted red;   }
textarea.check_valid:user-valid    { border: 4px solid  green; }

However this ONLY checks minlength / maxlength of the content in the textarea and not the content in the textarea.
However - I have server side validation ( in php ) that checks the content of the textarea and that is working fine. But i would like to add a green / red border like that on the other input fields when the content is as per the pattern ( which carries a regex )
d.) I am looking for a javascript snippet that will mimic the behaviour of check_valid:user-invalid / check_valid:user-valid when the user leaves the textarea after entering some content. The javascript snippet should check the content against a regex ( this achieving pattern support for the textarea )
This is what i have ( incomplete ) so far;
const textArea1 = document.getElementById("textarea1");

textArea1.addEventListener("change", (event) => {

  let patternTextArea1 = ~^[a-zA-Z0-9:\s,.'&()\/\-]{10,550}$~; 
   
  if ( // test textarea content against the regex ) {
  
      // apply user-valid - green border
    
  } else {
  
     // apply user-invalid - red dotted line
    
  }
  
});


My javascript skills is absymal as evidenced above.
Help will be most appreciated.

You have not actually asked a question or suggested what problems you are having other than "...this ONLY checks minlength / maxlength and not the content..." ~ is this a plea for help with your Javascript or CSS?

@ProfessorAbronsius - Pls look at d.)  That is what I am asking.

Have you tried testing the value of text area against the regex?  What is the problem you have found? Please show us that code (SO isn’t an ab initio coding service, but we are happy to look at code that is giving a problem).

@AHaworth - I am testing out the solutions offered below as well as other snippets. I am weak in JS :-) Will keep grinding.

Adding pattern check to a textarea
The textarea element does not have a pattern attribute, but you can add one using a data attribute.
In the change event you can test the pattern and use setCustomValidity to add a validation message.
The browser will automatically display the custom message the same way it does minlength, maxlength, and required value checks.

Notes:
There are pseudo classes for :invalid and :valid states that work automatically. Also, custom validation errors are in a fixed language, unlike standard pattern errors. Internationalization would require additional code (not shown).
Code Snippet
The example has been kept very simple to show how it works.


const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const reg = new RegExp(textarea.dataset.pattern, 'gmi');
  textarea.setCustomValidity('');
  if (!reg.test(textarea.value)) {
    textarea.setCustomValidity('Invalid characters in text');
  }
  textarea.reportValidity(); // optional - displays popup
})
textarea {
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 4px dotted black;
  outline: none;
}

textarea:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

textarea:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

textarea:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
<textarea 
  required 
  minlength="10" 
  maxlength="500" 
  placeholder="type some text here"
  data-pattern="(?<!\n)^[()\w\s]+$(?!\n)">
</textarea>




How will textarea.classList.add('check_valid') know to apply the color green (valid) or red ( invalid )?

Thanks. I am marking this as the Accepted Answer. I havent had time to get it done but i think this is the closest to what i want to do. Thanks x 3000.

When the change event happens on the textarea element you can set the same value on a hidden input element that has the pattern attribute.


// stop the default invalid message from showing
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  if (e.target.dataset.name) {
    // set the input to have the same value as the textarea
    form[e.target.dataset.name].value = e.target.value;
    // set class name according to validity
    e.target.classList.add('valid');
    if (!form[e.target.dataset.name].validity.valid) {
      e.target.classList.replace('valid', 'invalid');
    }
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log(...data);
});
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

textarea.invalid {
  border: 4px dotted red;
}

textarea.valid {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

input:user-invalid {
  border: 4px dotted red;
}

input:user-valid {
  border: 4px solid green;
}
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="other" pattern=".{2,10}" required>
  <textarea data-name="longtext" name=""></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="longtext"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9:\s,\.'&\(\)\/\-]{10,550}"
    style="display:none" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




Interesting but this is beyond me. Appreciate yr effort though. I am not looking to change my form submission code.

@MarcoZen I'm not saying that my way is the only way, but don't mess with the submit event if you are not doing AJAX etc. Use some of the other events for handling you logic for the form, like the change, invalid and input events etc.

You are asking how to force an element to be :user-valid or the other :user-invalid. Is this possible? Yes. Using inputField.setCustomValidity(msg). Well actually it will work for :valid and :invalid but we can change CSS for this, and toggle a class .user-interacted to check validity only when user interacted.
So that's 2 things: setCustomValidity, and adding a .user-interacted.


textarea.addEventListener("input", checkOnServer)

function checkOnServer(ev) {
  var elem = ev.target

  // this of course will use AJAX to query server
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add("user-interacted")
    var value = elem.value
    var msg = value.length > 3 ? '' : 'Length must be longer than 3 chars'
    elem.setCustomValidity(msg)
  }, 100)

}
textarea.check_valid.user-interacted:invalid {
  border: 4px dotted red;
}

textarea.check_valid.user-interacted:valid {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
}
<p>let's assume valid is > 3 chars</p>
<textarea id="textarea" class="check_valid" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>




Hi @IT Goldman. I am asking for a JS snippet that can implemet checking of textarea content against a regex as textarea doesnt have built in pattern support.

Also, why do we have to query the server via Ajax to perform textarea content validation ?

It doesn't matter, you can check anything you want in the function checkOnServer, including length, and regular expressions, client or server. Move you logic there. Or move the setCustomValidity logic into your function of checking.

Appreciate yr effort though.

I was under the impressions you wanted to validate on server. But again, all that matters is that if valid do setCustomValidity('') and if invalid do a setCustomValidity('error msg')
